# How to use the Headphone button as push to talk button in android

Tags: android

I want to use the Headphone button "KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK" as push to talk button in android, ie when press and hold i can do something then stop when I release it.
Thanks

here is my code

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK/*KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK*/ && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     Log.e("RAM","Set");
     setPushToTalk(true);
     return true;
     }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && (event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) == KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(!mService.isConnected()){
                playTone();
                return false ;
            }
            boolean waitFlag = false;
            for (User user : mService.getUserList()) {
                if (user.getChannel().equals(getChannel())) {
                    if (user.talkingState == 1)
                        waitFlag = true;// user);
                    // Log.e("Talking user",user.name+"/"+user.talkingState);
                }
            }
            if (waitFlag){
                sendWaitingMsg();
            }
            else{
                setPushToTalk(true);
            }
            Log.e("headphone btn", "down");
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            setPushToTalk(false);
            Log.e("headphone btn", "up");
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I have tried to make this button as a push to talk physical button but i'm facing a Button action time out issue so this make the action repeated each time as a new press !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK

it looks like its a single flag. it will only send a single message on press, holding will not  produce a steady input, you'd have to either 'toggle' talking using the button, perhaps allowing voice detection to function if a flag is toggled on/off by it OR avoid the keyEvent 
entirely and do hardware addressing?